# Non-commutative Galois theory

Tags: galois-theory, noncommutative-algebra, central-simple-algebras

Recall that an finite-dimensional algebra $A$ over a field $k$ is central simple iff there is an iso

$A \otimes_k A^{op} \cong M_n(k)$

where $A^{op}$ is the opposite ring and $M_n(k)$ is the matrix ring.

On the other hand, a finite field extension $K / k$ is Galois iff there is an iso

$K \otimes_k K \cong K^{Aut_k(K)}.$

These two statements strike me as similar and I am wondering:

1. Is there a Galois theory for non-commutative extensions in which the central simple algebras take the role of the Galois extensions in the usual Galois theory? Or, is there a theory which subsumes these two facts as some special cases?
2. Is there some sort of absolute "non-commutative" Galois group which features automorphisms of all non-commutative extensions of $k$ at a time? I could imagine this group $Gal_{nc}(k)$ to map (on?)to the usual group $Gal(k)$.

Thank you!

Comment: Your second statement is not correct: take $k=\mathbb{R}$ and $K=\mathbb{C}$

Comment: @Ofra: yes it is. The superscript denotes taking a product, not taking fixed points.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let $k$ be a field. Say that a $k$-algebra $A$ is **separable** if any of the following equivalent conditions holds (it is not obvious that they are equivalent):

1. $A$ is projective as an $(A, A)$-bimodule.
2. $A$ is geometrically semisimple in the sense that $A \otimes_k L$ is semisimple for any field extension $L$ of $k$.
3. $A \otimes_k A^{op}$ is semisimple.

> **Theorem:** The separable $k$-algebras are precisely the finite products of matrix algebras over finite-dimensional division algebras $D$ over $k$ whose centers $Z(D)$ are separable (in the usual sense) field extensions of $k$.

Hence the classification of separable algebras up to Morita equivalence is a mix of usual Galois theory and the classification of central simple algebras: the ones which are indecomposable with respect to product are classified by pairs of a finite separable extension $k \to L$ and a class in the Brauer group $\text{Br}(L)$ of $L$.

Over an arbitrary base $k$ the correct generalization requires an additional finiteness hypothesis: an algebra $A$ is **2-dualizable** if $A$ is finitely generated projective both as an $(A, A)$-bimodule and as a $k$-module. I think the classification of these is a mix of the classification of finite etale $k$-algebras and the classification of [Azumaya algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azumaya_algebra). The terminology comes from topological field theory: a 2-dualizable $k$-algebra defines a 2-dimensional topological field theory taking values in the Morita 2-category of $k$-algebras, bimodules, and bimodule homomorphisms.

Comment: As for the question about getting a bigger Galois group, the relevant group in this story is still the usual Galois group, but it's acting on more interesting things (categories instead of sets).

Comment: Could you extend a bit this comment ? (or pointing to a reference ?) Do we know a classification for those algebras ?

Comment: Is it possible that in 1. above it should be projective as a $k,k$-bimodule? Or otherwise how does it depend on $k$?

Comment: Dear Quiaochu, thank you for your answer! Can you please provide a reference for the statements above? Also, can you elaborate more on your comment that this "non-commutative" Galois group is the same as the usual one?

Comment: @Jakob: $k$ is commutative, and the only way it's acting on $A$ is from one side (which is equivalent to its action from the other side), so I don't know what bimodule structure you have in mind. I don't have a reference here besides the nLab; I'm in the middle of trying to prove this as an exercise myself. The Galois group comment is a reference to Galois descent.

Comment: @Qiaochu: thanks -- looking at the nlab it says there that it is separable iff $A$ is projective as a $A \otimes_k A^{op}$-module.

Comment: @Jakob: yes, that's equivalent to being projective as a bimodule (over $k$).

Comment: @Jakob: I have a reference now: https://qchu.wordpress.com/2016/03/27/separable-algebras/

Comment: Very good. Thank you, I appreciate it.