# Why does $E\otimes_KE\cong EG$ imply that Galois theory works?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, galois-theory, fields

This is a part of statement in the book I do not fully appreciate. Suppose $E/K$ is Galois extension and $G$ the Galois group of $E/K$. $E[G]$ is the group ring formed by finite group $G$.

*"It is worthwhile remarking that $E\otimes_KE\cong EG$ can be viewed as a deep reason why Galois theory works."* Ref: Algebra Vol 1: Fields and Galois Theory by Falko Lorenz.

**Q:** (solved by the comments below) What is the implication above? I thought $E\otimes_KE\cong EG$'s proof has a major ingredient that the trace map is non degenerate (i.e $E/K$ is separable). Is this affording some representation of $G\to \operatorname{Aut}_K(E)$? What is the author trying to express? Does this extend to infinite Galois extension case?

This question (**Q**) has been [asked on Stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2778581/) <s>but there is no answer</s>. Hence, I asked this on MO.

**Q':** As Qiaochu commented that this is related to torsor theory, I do not see why the two are related. It would be nice if someone could elaborate this a bit.

Comment: If $E/K$ is finite then $|\text{Aut}(E/K)| \leq [E:K]$, with equality if and only if $E/K$ is a Galois extension. With this in mind, compute the $E$-dimension of both sides, letting $G$ be $\text{Aut}(E/K)$.

Comment: @KConrad I should deduce that $dim_E(E\otimes_KE)\geq dim_E(E[G])$ as $Aut(E/K)\leq[E:K]$. The content of the $E\otimes_KE\cong EG$ is equivalent to $E/K$ is galois for finite extension case. Is this correct? I also know $k[G]\cong E$ as $k[G]$ modules though non-canonical. So for finite extension, $k[G]\cong E$ iff $E[G]\cong E\otimes_KE$ iff $E/K$ galois. Is this interpretation correct? And what can I conclude about infinite extension via inverse limit of galois group? Can I pull out the inverse limit as direct limit on the other side?

Comment: Hendrik Lenstra has a result that generalizes the isomorphism $K[G]\cong E$ in the infinite-degree Galois case: think of the group ring as the functions $G \rightarrow K$. When $G$ is infinite, work with *continuous* functions ($G$ with the Krull topology and $K$ with the discrete topology). The title of his article is "The normal basis theorem for infinite extensions," or something close to that.

Comment: @KConrad Thanks a lot for clarification and references.

Comment: Using the Krull-Schmidt theorem, the Deuring-Noether theorem shows that $E[G]\cong E\otimes_K E$ iff $k[G]\cong K$.  From this the fundamental theorem of Galois theory is pretty easy because it is trivial to see that the fixed subspace of a subgroup $H$ on $k[G]$ has dimension $[G:H]$ .  From this one easily gets that fundamental theorem of Galois theory.

Comment: The assertion is equivalent to the normal basis theorem which some books do use to give the fundamental theorem of Galois theory.

Comment: Closely related: [Non-commutative Galois theory](https://mathoverflow.net/q/234066/41291)

Comment: Are $EG$ and $E[G]$ just alternative notations for the same thing?

Comment: @GerryMyerson $EG=E[G]$. Sorry for the confusion. They are the same thing.

Comment: For the relation to torsors in your second question,  the point is that the normal basis theorem could be seen as a consequence of Galois descent for algebras.

Comment: @KConrad's [reference](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/300197/why-does-e-otimes-ke-cong-eg-imply-that-galois-theory-works#comment747153_300197):  Lenstra - A normal basis theorem for infinite Galois extensions ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=799082)).

Answer (score 3):

This is a CW answer to note that I answered this question over at math.SE. If someone upvotes this, it will be removed from the unanswered list.

Comment: The [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3480574) on MSE.